# How to create key-value pairs DStream in Spark Streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm new to Spark Streaming. There's a project using Spark Streaming, the input is a key-value pair string like "productid,price".

The requirement is to process each line as a separate transaction, and make RDD triggered every 1 second.

In each interval I have to calculate the total price for each individual product, like

```
select productid, sum(price) from T group by productid
```

> My current thought is that I have to do the following steps 
>   1) split the whole line with \n val lineMap = lines.map{x=>x.split("\n")}
>
> 2) split each line with "," val
>   recordMap=lineMap.map{x=>x.map{y=>y.split(",")}}

Now I'm confused about how to make the first column as key and second column as value, and use **reduceByKey** function to get the total sum.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Once you have split each row, you can do something like this:

```
rowItems.map { case Seq(product, price) => product -> price }
```

This way you obtain a `DStream[(String, String)]` on which you can apply pair transformations like `reduceByKey` (don't forget to import the required implicits).